# PHP - Rewrite foreach loop as a for loop to have a counter

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to rewrite two `foreach` loops as `for` loops so that I am able to stop them at 3. Here is the first and simple loop's original:

```
<?php foreach ($marketing[0]['values'] as $company) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $company['label']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $company['value']; ?></td>
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

Here is my attempted re-write:

```
 <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) { 
        $company = $marketing[0][$i]['values']; 
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $company['label']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $company['value']; ?></td>
        </tr>            
      <?php } ?>
```

Here is the second and slightly more complicated `foreach` loop that I haven't attempted yet.

```
<?php foreach ($sales as $sale) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $sale['key']; ?></td>
            <td>
              <?php 
                foreach ($sale['values'] as $values) {
                  if ($values['x'] == $currentTeam) {
                    echo $values['y'];
                  }
                }                 
              ?>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

Comment: `$company = $marketing[0]['values'][$i]; `

Comment: Btw, what is the point for such a rewrite? Why cannot you just stop `foreach` with `break`?

Comment: You can also stop foreach loops at 3 as well.

Comment: I'm simply open to the best possibly implementation. The examples of `break` I found didn't match the kind of code I was using so not sure how to implemented.

Comment: @dvoutt: "I'm simply open to the best possibly implementation" --- your question lacks the explanation of the real issue to help you. Now this question is a great example of an XY-problem

Comment: @zerkms the issue is that I need for a visual purpose to cut off the list. I'm also going to sort the table by highest to lowest value which is my next step. Basically a top three sales and marketing spend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use break. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($marketing[0]['values'] as $company) { ?>
    <?php if ($counter == $maxLimit) break; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $company['label']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $company['value']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: To go further one may combine them `if (++$counter <= $maxLimit) break; `

Comment: For some reason the editor is stripping out the closing PHP tags on lines 1 and 8. Make sure to include those.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there already

```
<?php 
  $maxLimit = 3; //you could get maxlimit from elsewhere rather than hardcoding it

  //use count() to get the length of an array in PHP
  for($i = 0; $i < count($marketing[0]); ++$i) 
  { 
    $company = $marketing[0][$i]['values']; 
    if($i > $maxLimit) break;
  ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $company['label']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $company['value']; ?></td>
    </tr>            
  <?php } ?>
```

As an alternative, you could introduce a counter field on the side

```
      <?php 
          $salesCounter = 0;
          $maxSalesCounter = 3;
          foreach ($sales as $sale) 
          { 
      ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sale['key']; ?></td>
        <td>
          <?php 
            foreach ($sale['values'] as $values) 
            {
              if($salesCounter > maxSalesCounter) break;
              if ($values['x'] == $currentTeam) 
              {
                echo $values['y'];
                $salesCounter++;
              }

            }                 
          ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Or use the minimum of 3 and `count`.